# uno platform: GetManifestResourceNames returns nothing

Tags: .net-assembly, embedded-resource, uno-platform

For the Uno platform, I need to load an image from "content" resources. I'm using `GetManifestResourceStream`, but it's returning null while running the UWP project (I haven't tried the other flavors).

To dig a bit further, I added `GetManifestResourceNames`, but it is also returning an empty array.

Here's my code, which is inside a `UserControl` (`Source` is a property):

```
private void LoadBmpSrc()
{
  if (Source == null)
    return;

  Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
  string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
  using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(Source))
  {
    bmpSrc = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
  }
}
```

In the consuming XAML file, I have this, inside a `Grid`:

```
  <controls:ExpandableImage 
    Grid.Column="0"
    Source="ms-appx:///Assets/icons/folder_tab.png" 
    />
```

If I swap in this code:

```
  <Image 
    Grid.Column="0" 
    Source="ms-appx:///Assets/icons/folder_tab.png" 
    />
```

the image displays.

EDIT

Here's the XAML for the control:

```
<UserControl
  x:Class="UnoTest.Shared.Controls.ExpandableImage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="using:UnoTest.Shared.Controls"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:skia="using:SkiaSharp.Views.UWP"
  >

  <skia:SKXamlCanvas x:Name="EICanvas" PaintSurface="OnPaintSurface" />
  
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is basically that the `Content` images are not treated as `Resources`.

If you want to include images as a Resource you will need to change the **Build Action** of that file into **Embedded Resource**. Once you change this it will show up in the

```
string[] names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

method call.

You will notice that the name of the image will be something like `ApplicationName.Directory.ImageName.png`. You will need to specify this name in order to load the image with the

```
assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(imageName)
```

If you want to load a Content `Image` data and into a Stream you could do that (haven't test it) with the following code:

```
var imageUrl = "ms-appx:///Assets/SplashScreen.png";
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(imageUrl));
        
using(var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
{
   //Use your data here
}
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: I'll try your suggestion. Do you know, then, how <Image /> is loading the files when they are marked as "content" ? I'll presume the answer is the second half of your response.

Comment: The `Source` property for an `Image` is an `ImageSource` (https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/blob/ef5961fd9bf1fb6c617de6842ff4cc3643fdf47b/src/Uno.UI/UI/Xaml/Media/ImageSource.cs)  and this is the one responsible for "loading" the file. The actual implementation does vary between Platforms.

Comment: This (content approach) works, except you have to explicitly type the result from GetFile... as StorageFile.